# File Name Rename - Substring Date Removal

Tags: bash

I'm trying to rename a list of files with file names in format ABCD-YYMMDD-HHMMSS-EFGH to just ABCD-EFGH.

For example I have following:

Case1-20170309-110213-TOCLOSE
Case2-20170416-110314-TOCLOSE
Case3-20171112-110715-TOCLOSE

And I want them to be renamed to:

Case1-TOCLOSE
Case2-TOCLOSE
Case3-TOCLOSE

Basically I just want to get rid of the date and time embedded in the file names. As the date and time are all different, the only way I can think of is to rename the -*-*- pattern to just -

After research I tried following but no success:

rename 's/-*-*-/-/' *

Sorry as I'm completely bash script beginner here I could really use some guidance.

Thank you.

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `rename` (`prename`):

```
rename -n 's/^([^-]+-).*-([^-]+$)$/$1$2/' *-*-*-*
```

- `^([^-]+-)` gets the portion till first `-` from start, and put the match in captured group 1
- `([^-]+$)$ gets the portion at end after last`-`, and put the match in captured group 2
- In the replacement, the two captured groups are used, `$1$2`

`-n` does the try-run, remove `-n` for actual action.

---

With shell paramter expansion, to get the required portion:

```
for f in *-*-*-*; do echo mv -i "$f" "${f%%-*}-${f##*-}"; done
```

- `${f%%-*}` strips off everything from first `-` from variable `f`
- `${f##*-}` drops the substring till last `-`
  Remove `echo` for actual action.

---

**Example:**

```
% rename -n 's/^([^-]+-).*-([^-]+$)$/$1$2/' *-*-*-*
Case1-20170309-110213-TOCLOSE renamed as Case1-TOCLOSE
Case2-20170416-110314-TOCLOSE renamed as Case2-TOCLOSE
Case3-20171112-110715-TOCLOSE renamed as Case3-TOCLOSE

% for f in *-*-*-*; do echo mv -i "$f" "${f%%-*}-${f##*-}"; done
mv -i Case1-20170309-110213-TOCLOSE Case1-TOCLOSE
mv -i Case2-20170416-110314-TOCLOSE Case2-TOCLOSE
mv -i Case3-20171112-110715-TOCLOSE Case3-TOCLOSE
```

Comment: Very detailed explanation and it does the job! Thank you for your help!